# XMLHttpRequest with a file from a 3rd party server

Tags: javascript, blob, epub, xmlhttprequest

First of all, forgive my english please..

Is it possible to retrieve a file using a xmlhttp GET Request with the url parameter that is an address to a file not located in the server, but in another server?

```
<script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "url/of/file.epub", true);
request.responseType = "blob";
request.onload = function () {
    new Epub(request.response, function (bookData) {
        Monocle.Reader("reader", bookData);
    });
};
request.send();
</script>
```

In the example above an XMLHttpRequest has been made to return a blob

Comment: possible duplicate of [cross domain XMLHttprequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144093/cross-domain-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can use the [forcecors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcecors/) plugin for Firefox to have FF ignore the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (because all responses have [cors headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)).

The other option would be [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) but since you've already mentioned blob data it isn't an option since JSONP only works with JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you tagged this "epub" because you are trying to do this within an e-book, you're out of luck. `XMLHttpRequest` won't work at all.